# process.env.NODE_ENV suddenly UNDEFINED in current SvelteKit project

Tags: node.js, vite, sveltekit

Inside `svelte.config.js` I was using this

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
```

to conditionally set a base path which was working fine in projects with `@sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.350`  and `*.357`

After installing now the most recent SvelteKit version `@sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.386` it only results to `undefined`

Differences I notice is that the new project lists `"vite": "^3.0.0"` as devDependency and the script changed from `"dev": "svelte-kit dev",` to `"dev": "vite dev"`

Update: It's also the case for a project with `@sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.366`, `vite@2.9.14`, `"dev": "vite dev"` - so the switch was before vite 3.0

Going through the vite docs I find `import.meta.env`, but that's also `undefined` inside `svelte.config.js`

Switching from Node v16 to 17 didn't make a difference as well

What changed and how can I now distinguish between `dev` and `build` mode?

Comment: Hint: backticks  do not work in question string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you describe was introduced in [100-next384](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/packages/kit/CHANGELOG.md#100-next384)

> [breaking] remove mode, prod and server from $app/env (#5602)

and [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/5602) is the relevant discussion

> respect --mode, and remove server, prod and mode from $app/env

I think you should use [Vite capabilities](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html) to configure dev VS production/build modes.

### Update

Considering better your case, a way to solve the issue is to set a value for the `NODE_DEV` environment variable, like (Linux/Mac):

```
export NODE_ENV=development && npm run dev
```

There are other ways to do this but at least for development it should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure - is this really related to `$app/env`? I'm not in a `src/` project file but in the `svelte.config.js`. I first thought it was only with the current version and somehow related to vite 3, but it's the same in a project with `next.366` and `vite@2.9.14`. The vite docs page you linked is where I got `import.meta.env` from which as stated unforunately doesn't work in the config file.

Comment: I see what you say. Then, shouldn't be enough to export `NODE_ENV` environment variable?

Comment: export how/where?

Comment: it depends on your environment/os. for linux development I run `export NODE_ENV='dev' npm run dev`. ymmv

Comment: I'm on Mac and `export NODE_ENV=development && ...` seems to be doing the trick, great! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone in the future. I encountered this error when I created an express server in a react application. I created the server directory in the root folder of the react application and I was running both react app and express server at the same time.